# constructor exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Tags: java, arrays, limit

I have a class where I store the terrain of the world of my game. The gameworld consists of cubes and every cube has a terrain. The information is stored as a pretty big 3D-Array of integers.

The problem that I now encounter is that my 'map' is too big to store in a class (or enum). Since I don't really know anything outside of classes and enums, I don't know what to do with this.

Should i make a tekst file out of it and read that out? If so, how do I do that?

A different solution would be to split the map over several classes or enums and then merge them again at runtime, but I don't know how to do that either and it seems like a pretty bad solution.

EDIT: This is part of the worldmap:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

There are 40 of of these blocks (so 38 more) and each one represents the world at a certain z-coordinate. I also have this in arrayformat.
It would be great if you could provide some (sample) code on how to read this from a file.

Comment: I suggest that you don't split it in different classes, just store in a file.

Comment: Try a memory mapped approach, and read the memory in sections as you need it.

Comment: Rather than the array being defined as literals in code, you could store the data in a file and read from the disk to get it into the array.

Comment: @Jay I need the whole thing the initialize the world.

Comment: @Jire I was thinking about that, but as my question states: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Yea but your only reading a section ar a time to read it fully, you don't to read the whole thing in one read and you can't since it spandex multiple blocks and maybe pages. Memory map the file and read it fully where you need to.

Comment: @Sander Then you need to supply some code and more information. We can give you an implementation but we must know the format of your data first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better to put it into resource. Just create a text file next to your class (e.g. named `map.txt`), put there your world map in the same format you've used in the question, then load it using the code like this:

```
public int[][][] loadMap() {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass()
            .getResourceAsStream("map.txt"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))) {

        List<int[][]> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<int[]> cur = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            if(line.isEmpty() && !cur.isEmpty()) {
                result.add(cur.toArray(new int[0][]));
                cur.clear();
            } else {
                String[] cells = line.split("\\s+");
                int[] row = new int[cells.length];
                for(int i=0; i<cells.length; i++) row[i] = Integer.parseInt(cells[i]);
                cur.add(row);
            }
        }
        if(!cur.isEmpty())
            result.add(cur.toArray(new int[0][]));
        return result.toArray(new int[0][][]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible in your use case you could use blocks of `byte[]` instead, or even `short[]`. Then you should be well within the `65535` byte limit.

```
size för byte[] : 20 x 20 x 40 x 1 = 16000 bytes
size för short[]: 20 x 20 x 40 x 2 = 32000 bytes
```

Comment: this could be a solution for my smaller maps but they go up to 80x80x80 = 512 000 so for the bigger maps it would still be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your error?

If you don´t need all your map be loaded you can divide your map by chunks, and save all your map in a Xml for example, like this:

```
<map>
   <chunk x=0 y=0> 
      <!--chunk informations>
   </chunk>
   <chunk x=0 y=1> 
      <!--chunk informations>
   </chunk>
   <!--other chunks>
</map>
```

Comment: I need the whole thing the initialize the world. And it would be a lot easier to just have the entire world accessable at once. But still: I don't know how to load information from another file

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html

Comment: So @Sander you don´t know how to read text files?
You can use the Scanner class. It's very simple to learn, but you need to come more
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

If you want to use Xml (I think is a better choice) you can use the DOM Parser. It's a little difficult to learn, but you need to code less.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html

Comment: @bhspencer 
But I don´t have the 50 of reputation to comment in the question.
So I needed to write a answer.

Comment: @Pmso you are not going to gain much reputation by writing comments as answers.